# fatal: no such path 'A' in HEAD using fugitive plugin

Tags: plugin-fugitive, vim8

I've my little vim distro with tpope/vim-fugitive installed. Using `Git blame` in little project (little means with few folders) works fine. Used with files with a deep tree of folders give me a bad result: the `blame` part is so huge that the editor part contains just few columns. I can fix this with `Ctrl-w 20>`. Is there a way to configure fugitive without file name and just committer name?

Reading documentation I saw the following stuffs (I removed some parts not very interesting for this question).

```
                                                *:Git_blame*
:Git blame [flags]      Run git-blame [flags] on the current file and open the
                        results in a scroll-bound vertical split.  The
                        following maps, which work on the cursor line commit
                        where sensible, are provided:

                        A     resize to end of author column
```

I suppose the command I am looking for is `:Git blame A`.

Running the previous command vim responds with the following message:

```
fatal: no such path 'A' in HEAD
```

So, ...

Answer (score 1):

You must press `A` in the blame info window.  It is not a command argument.

The preceding text is relevant:

> The following maps, which work on the cursor line commit where sensible, are provided: